# Is there a way to compile python code in flutter apps itself?

Tags: python, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

Is there a way to compile python code in flutter apps itself ?

> Note :- I did a bit of research and ended up with solutions which
> wanted a dedicated server for python code to be hosted and later on I
> could pass a query and get response which is not exactly I am aiming
> for. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awesome So I came up with a solution for which we need to use a package named **Starflut**.
Just read the documentation on the first page of the package and you will understand how to implement it!

> Link :- [Starflut](https://pub.dev/packages/starflut)

Happy Coding !

Comment: should not use python for mobile application development.

Comment: friend why so ?

Comment: Do you know how to import python libraries?